# Need help removing [...] after excerpt

Tags: php, posts, css, html, excerpt

My website is watersedgeofshelton.com and i need help removing the [...] after the excerpts on the blog posts (under activities, marinas and restaurants"

I read that I had to add this code to my functions php

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

but when i added that, it did not work, any suggestions?

my functions php looks like this

```
// The excerpt based on words
if ( !function_exists('my_string_limit_words') ) {
    function my_string_limit_words($string, $word_limit){
        $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
        if( count($words) > $word_limit )
            array_pop($words);
        return implode(' ', $words).'...';
    }
}


// The excerpt based on character
if ( !function_exists('my_string_limit_char') ) {
    function my_string_limit_char($excerpt, $substr=0){
        $string = strip_tags(str_replace( '...', '...', $excerpt));
        if ( $substr > 0 ) {
            $string = substr($string, 0, $substr);
        }
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first code (`add_filter('excerpt_more', '...');`) works for me

Comment: @Pierre where do i place this in the functions file?

Comment: Yep! Where did you put this forward?

Comment: @Pierre do i put it after the <?php

Answer (score 1):

This has to work, Im using it in several projects:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'my_excerpt_more' );

function my_excerpt_more( $more ) {

    return '';
}
```

Just copy-paste it to your `functions.php`.

---

Little bonus snippet that you might need:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length' );

function my_excerpt_length( $length ) {

    return 50;
}
```

This means that excerpt is 50 words long. Just modify the number to get different length.

Comment: do i add this just after the <?php ?

Comment: Attention the hook `excerpt_length` returns a number of words and not characters ;-)

Comment: @sara Im personally adding filters to the end of `functions.php`.